# Documenting code changes

Tags: c#, java, coding-style

What are the different ways code changes can be documented?
I'm currently working on code which is going through lots of changes. The current convention to document the code change is something like

```
//Begin add by xxxx for feature/bug xxxx <Date>
........
........
//End add by xxxxx for feature/bug XXXX <Date>
```

This sloppy way of commenting has produced a lot of mess. We hunt for actual lines of code through the thick comments. We don't want to record the changes in the checkin-comments section of the version control software. I'm thinking of maintaining a changelog at the beginning of the file, where all the changes are documented. What are the ways you guys use to document the changes?

Comment: Why, oh why don't you want to use version control for it? One of its purposes is to avoid this kind of mess!

Comment: @NiklasB. we've a very weird situation, where regularly, the code branches and is stored in a different version control software.

Comment: @Rnet Then you should alter your version control approach. Using two different types of version control software is stupid, and good version control should be able to handle branches well (*uch* not subversion *uch*)

Comment: Rnet: If the reason is that you have your code located on different servers, you might consider switching to a decentralized version control system like Git. It can do any kind of branching you could possibly imagine.

Comment: @dtech Yes, an unfortunate situation, we act as a base to three other teams.

Comment: Git handles branching very well, and is an industry standard. And if you host your code on [GitHub](http://github.com/), it is *very* easy to see the most recent changes, who made them, and what the comments are. And as for "acting as a base for other teams," that is *all the more reason* that you should be working in the same repository!!

Comment: @DavidRobinson True, unfortunately that decision is not in my hands. There was a time when the code hopped vss, svn, cvs and back to svn again. Very painful.

Comment: @Rnet: If you are the one worrying about how this mess should be managed in the future, you might just as well be the one who stands up and tries to convince his coworkers and superiors that the current approach isn't going to work. I doubt that you will get a good answer apart from "we use version control for that, and you should too", because that is the only sensible advise :)

Comment: @NiklasB.Yes, I realized that, Thanks :)

Comment: Good luck, @Rnet! You can convince them to use one version control system! We believe in you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will find that in practice, the important information is what the code does *now*, not how it got there. By obscuring the current code with these kinds of comments, you are making the code much harder to read and work with.

On the occasion that you need to go back and see *why* something was done, all the information is best captured in version control. Don't try to capture history in the code itself.

Answer (score 5):

Your version control system should be the main source of change information. Comments about non-obvious functionality in the code should be documented as comments, regardless of reason, i.e. whether it is for a change or not.

The programmer that changed the code, the related bug/feature that was the reason for the change, and the time of the change ALL of that is already encoded in the changelog of the file that your version control system creates! Any more manually added changelog, and it will be out of date, and clutter up the file.

Answer (score 4):

I would never do this in code. Never ever.
Comments should be minimal, and only to make confusing logic in code more clear (or, more often, to point out conventions). Always commit each change separately. Write a concise max 79chars commit message. You can keep a restructured text - e.g. CHANGES.rst - in the root of each packet (product). That's how we do - you can take a look [here](http://svn.eionet.europa.eu/projects/Naaya/browser/trunk/eggs/Naaya/CHANGELOG.rst).

You can also use a ticketing/pm system and mention ticket in commit message.

Comment: That document seems to be no more than a collection of commit messages. Why do you put it into version control instead of dynamically generating it using a small script?

Comment: @NiklasB. - Good question! Best answer I can think of now is because we have no connection between release numbers and commits, and we use these release versions in deployment. We need to know what changed between two releases, and not between two commits. And we also include this file in packaging each release

Comment: @Mihnea: Well, SVN has tags, so you could also create changelogs between versions. I mainly wondered how you created that file in the first place (because it seems cumbersome to generate it by hand, seeing that the included information is readily available for machine processing). Just mentioning because I don't think it's a good idea to check these files into version control.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'll look into tags, I know somebody in our team had an objection for that but I do not remember that.

Comment: And yes, your guess is correctly, this is then parsed by an internal tool so we can annotate even more - what update procedure is required to be made in production, what affects the end user etc.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Going to sleep now, good night :)

Comment: "max 79 chars" is precisely one of those non-obvious statements that should come with a comment of some kind :D 
Is it to be able to read a log in a console window?

Comment: @AndersForsgren - Yes, actually 50. The 79 limit is a good style practice for writing code (max width of a terminal). If you use vim for editing commits, it will color different the first 50 chars. You can describe your commit in multiline text, but the first line should be the summary. First line is used as a summary by other apps, like Trac, when displaying lists of revisions in web interface. I see somebody wrote about [this](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html)